# Why does FPS show 30 when im trying to get 60?

Tags: c, sdl

```
while( quit == -1 )
    {
        // Did user quit?
        while( SDL_PollEvent( &sdlEvent ) )
            if( sdlEvent.type == SDL_QUIT )
                quit = 1;

        // Apply surfaces
        ApplySurface(0, 0, background, screen);

        // Flip the screen
        if( SDL_Flip( screen ) == -1 )
            return 1;

        ++numFrames;
        sprintf( fpsbuff, "FPS: %.0f", (numFrames/(float)(SDL_GetTicks() - startTime))*1000);
        SDL_WM_SetCaption(fpsbuff, NULL);

        // Regulate FPS
        currTime = SDL_GetTicks();
        if( oldTime != 0 )
            if( currTime - oldTime < 60 )
                SDL_Delay(60 - (currTime-oldTime));
        oldTime = currTime;
    }
```

im trying to lock the FPS to 60, are some of my calculations wrong?

Any other smart way to lock the FPS to a value?

Comment: Didn't look at the code, but have you checked to see if your driver has vsync enabled or not? (Side note: Instead of writing code to limit the frame rate, you can use vsync!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

60 FPS ~= 16.7 ms/f. Fix the parameter in `SDL_Delay`.

BTW: For the future, get the habit of using ms/f instead of fps - this measure is actually much easier to work with.

BTW2: 60FPS with SDL? You are going to need hardware acceleration and I'm afraid SDL by itself won't provide it for you. Consider SDL+OpenGL or SFML perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because your system can't keep up with 60 fps.  Just because you tell it to doesn't mean it will be able to.

Comment: The demo program should be able to keep up with 60FPS.